# Which version of percona db package should i install in ubuntu Natty Narwhal?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu, natty, percona

I am new to both percona & Ubuntu. According to this [page](http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.1/Percona-Server-5.1.55-12.6/deb/) percona is only available for

```
* etch
* hardy
* lenny
* lucid
* maverick
* squeeze
```

But i am using 11.04 (Natty). Can someone recommend me which version should i choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've installed and run maerick's on natty without an issue... when they do release a natty version though I'll swap it out. hope this helps.